# Structuring JMeter Test Plan

Tags: testing, jmeter

I want to load test RUN operation with 500 users. So I set threads as 500 in thread group.
I have a header parameter "username" for the RUN request.

Now, I want to have different username for each request. How do I do it? Do I need a CSV Data Set Config? But then while controller would be needed. And it will go through entire csv for each thread (user), which I don't want.

So how do I do it?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: @DavidBaak Please can you show an example?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far (code)?

Comment: I accepted your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the CSV Data Set Config.

See [this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) for working of it.

Make sure your thread settings are correct. You do not need the while controller.

Comment: Hi @user5155835, what kind thread controller do you have? Post a screenshot, makes life easier

Comment: Hi @user5155835 That is how the csv data set config works, you don't have to do anything for it to go the next username

Comment: I understand your question @user5155835. You want it to start a new thread with a user that has not been used yet. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi, please accept the edit and I'll accept the answer. Let me know once you accept the edit

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy explains how CSV Data Set Config works